# App Shell Components

Tags: angular

Well, I have an app which has top-nav, top-filter, etc which are common, only the view changes as route change, views are `Spreadsheet` & `Two panel`. So I have created a parent component which calls other components (header, filter, spreadsheet & two panel). In the route, I am calling parent component for both spreadsheet & two panel like this:

```
{ path: 'two-panel', component: ContactParent },
{ path: 'spreadsheet', component: ContactParent }
```

and here is parent components template:

```
<top-nav></top-nav>
<top-filter></top-filter>

<spreadsheet *ngIf="currentUrl == '/spreadsheet'"></spreadsheet>
<two-panel *ngIf="currentUrl == '/two-panel'"></two-panel>

<cancel-payment></cancel-payment>
<delete-dialog></delete-dialog>
<create-link></create-link>
<message></message>
```

So here everything is working fine, now since on the first refresh I already got these common components (top-nav, top-filter, etc) resolved why they are again reloading on route change, how I can avoid this? For better understanding here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't see <router-outlet /> in your code. Not sure how are you managing routing in your app. I believe the components top-nav and top-filter are reloading if they are residing in the parent <router-outlet />. I believe you should use routing instead of ng-if

Comment: You should put `spreadsheet` and `two-panel` component in router, and delcare <router-outlet> on parent template.

Comment: Well I don't want to put spreadsheet & two-panel in router but declaring `router-outlet` in parent makes sense, with some work around I think my problem will be solved. Thanks guys...